# Capturing Email address from the webpage which uses webcollect form inorder to update the subscriberstatus

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl, webstudio

Using a webcollect in a website we are getting the subscribers for the newsletter ,if the subscriber unsubscribed from the same newsletter but after sometime they go to the website to sign up again to the newsletter .In this case how to get the email address from the form page and send that to a landing page where it will ask for a confirmation  and navigate to another page to update the subscriber stauts in the list.

in this case the updating subscriber status is working fine but I dont know how to capture the email address from the web page and pass it on to the cloudpage

Comment: If you are using CloudPagesURL to bridge the two pages, you might be able to use the personalization string - %%emailaddr%% to the print email address or assign to a variable (Set @passedEmail = emailaddr).

Comment: Im using two landing page one to get the email address from the subscriber and LP 2 to update the status . the issue is THe landing page 2 is not getting the parameter value from landing page 1 . i have used html <input type=email Value="" name=Email Address/> in LP1 and in LP2 i used request parameters to get the value ,but its void

Comment: Could you post snippets of your code from page 1, as well as how you're using the code on page 2? There are a few ways to accomplish what you want - and I would like to work through an approach that won't require you to blow up your current build.

Comment: <label>Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="Email Address">